# rvm cannot install ruby-1.9.3-p484

Tags: ruby, rvm, octopress

I am trying to update my OctoPress Blog and get the error

ruby-1.9.3-p484 is not installed.

When I type the command

rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484 I get the erros:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Error: No available formula for gcc46 
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.........
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p484',
please read /Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/log/1386191431_ruby-1.9.3-p484/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Not sure what's going on here. I currently have

```
ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
```

installed on my computer.

Comment: Please read the output closely `Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p484',
please read /Users/stevenbrooks1111/.rvm/log/1386191431_ruby-1.9.3-p484/update_system.log` if you do not understand the error in log file - add it to the question.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe RVM is out of date. Try

```
rvm get head
rvm install 1.9.3
```

**Edit**

You are also getting an error about gcc46. Ruby 1.9.3 shouldn't need gcc, since you already have clang. Try this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have an old version of Xcode installed.

In my case, I had the newest Command Line Tools but also the old version of Xcode.

I thought it'd be all fine. But it wasn't.